# TestDisk doesn't write partition table

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, data-recovery

I'm using TestDisk to try recover a disk with a single ext4 partition which I can see with TestDisk, but can't write (the partition table). I can browse files from TestDisk, but after writting I have no results.

This is a *Seagate Expansion Portable Hard Drive 1 TB* connected through USB. The drive contains 2 bad sectors reported.

Is there a well known explanation for this? What other partition recovering tool I may try from ArchLinux?

Comment: You should be thankful for this! If you are to write to the disk you're trying to recover you can make the situation even worse. NEVER write to the disk you're trying to recover. Don't do it. Just don't. Terrible idea.  There is a way of course to make use of the spare sectors but that's quite complicated and I’m not going to even try explaining that. Hopefully you've worked it out but for future reference always duplicate the disk and work on the copy (but don't write to it either if you can avoid it at all). But make sure you have a disk to write to that's not the bad disk.

Comment: Clarifying that: it's good to have a copy of the disk in case something goes wrong but you don't necessarily need a third disk; the point is to never write to the disk you're trying to recover. The reason it's good if you can have another disk is that you can be certain the volume(s) that are damaged are 'backed up' themselves (yes it might seem ridiculous to back up corrupted volumes but it's a good idea if you're playing with this type of thing).